# Page Analytics: Google Analytics orange tags not appearing

Tags: google-analytics

I have got the following code in a webpage but it is not showing but Page analytics is not displaying the google analytics orange tag:

```
<a href="http://player.vimeo.com/video/60376261" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'HOME PAGE', 'PLAY', 'WHY US', 100]);">
    <img src="/images/play-video-home.jpg" alt="Guests Love Dark Rome" width="700" height="380" />
</a>
```

On the same page I have some similar code which is virtually identical but it is displaying google analytics (orange) tag:

```
<div class="leftBoxLabel">
<a href="/official-vatican-museum-partnership" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'VATICAN PARTNER', 'Click', 'Vatican Partner']); ">
   <img src="/images/vaticanp.png" alt="" style="padding-left: 60px; margin-bottom: 80px; margin-top: 20px;" />
</a>
</div>
```

Why does the orange tag not appear when I select page analysis (with the google analytics plugin).  I set show clicks to 0.00%.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by a Google Analytics orange tag?

Comment: On Google Analytics a orange tag will appear on your page showing the amount of clicks (in percent) of users actions.  It is used for tracking and marketing.

Comment: Really? I have never seen a website displaying a Google analytics orange tag.  Are you sure this isn't some plugin you have?

Comment: yes its a plugin called Page Analytics.  But it shows some tags working and the other not. I wanted to fix the tags that weren't showing

Comment: do you know what could be wrong ?